# np.dot taking very long to run

Tags: numpy

I'm implementing a matrix factorization algorithm with numpy and found that my code was running for a long time and causing the jupyter kernel to restart. I localised the error to 1 line of code which is using np.dot. A snippet of code with the lines that run slowly is below:

```
H = np.random.rand(n_features, 8)
print(H_start.T.shape) #(8, 10285)
print(t2t_matrix.shape) #(10285, 10285)
S_nom = H_start.T.dot(t2t_matrix) # this line takes a long time
```

Any ideas? I would not have thought a (10285, 10285) matrix would take so long?

Comment: You printed `H_start` shape but you used `H` in the dot.

Comment: What is a "very long time"?

Comment: very long time = more than an hour and then it would crash jupyter notebook. See my answer below - it was actually performing a dot product using different matrix types.

Comment: Not a very helpful example when we don't know how t2t_matrix was generated. There is no possible way that anyone would've been able to catch the difference in data type with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that t2t_matrix was a 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix' and 
H_start was a 'numpy.ndarray'. I had to convert t2t_matrix using t2t_matrix.toarray(). Without the conversion, jupyter notebook would crash.

Comment: Yes, `dense.dot(sparse)` does not work correctly.  `sparse.dot(dense)` is fine, as is `sparse*sparse`.  But the plain dense `dot` attempts a naive conversion from sparse to dense, which is wrong.  Compare `np.array(t2t_matrix)` with `t2t_matrix.toarray()`.